# Local extrema of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I solved a question to find the local extrema of the function 
$$\frac{x^2 - 4}{x^2 - 1}$$
I got $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{6x}{(x^2 - 1)^2}$$
And the second derivative to be
$$\frac{6 - 18x^2}{(x^2 - 1)^3}$$
The critical point putting $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ is $x=0$
Inserting $x=0$ in the second derivative,
$$\frac{6-0}{0-1} = - 6$$
This should give a local maximum as the second derivative is negative but the answer in my text says its a local minimum,  is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ for any equations or math symbols on this website.

Answer (score 1):

the second derivative computation is wrong. it should be $\frac{-6-18x^2}{(x^2-1)^3}$
hope,That clarifies.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw the mistake.